# Kafka metrics(published msgs,consumed msgs e.t.c ) to spark streaming as a monitor

Tags: monitoring, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, metrics

I need to send kafka metrics (like how many messages published and how many consumed, etc.) to Spark streaming. I tried checking; there are some monitoring tools but not useful to me.  Is there a recommended pattern for this integration?

Comment: you can use kafka-manager from yahoo or or send kafka logs and process them yourself. A down point for kafka-manager is it assumes you use zookeeper to keep track of your consumed messages